# Asp.net core 2.1 to Asp.net 3.0 upgrade

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a web api application which is working fine in 2.1.
I am using same application to host in IIS on windows and without IIS on linux.
Now I am trying to upgrade the application.

I have upgraded the nuget packages and project version successfully.Now when trying to debug app looks there is some problem in my congiruation startup class which is as below

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

            StartupShutdownHandler.BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
}


namespace MyApp
{
    public class StartupShutdownHandler
    {

        public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<StartupShutdownHandler>();

        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private const string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public StartupShutdownHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            //services.AddMvc(options => { options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(); //this is changed in 3.0
            services.AddMvc(options => { options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            CorsRelatedPolicyAddition(services);
        }

        private void CorsRelatedPolicyAddition(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var lstofCors = ConfigurationHandler.GetSection<List<string>>(StringConstants.AppSettingsKeys.CorsWhitelistedUrl);
            if (lstofCors != null && lstofCors.Count > 0 && lstofCors.Any(h => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(h)))
            {                
                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => { builder.WithOrigins(lstofCors.ToArray()).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
                });

            }
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            //app.UseMvc(); //this is changed in 3.0
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(StartedApplication);
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
        }


        private void OnShutdown()
        {
             Logger.Debug("Application Shutdown");
        }

        private void StartedApplication()
        {
            Logger.Debug("Application Started");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried chagned some lines which are commented as //this is changed in 3.0 but it doesn't work.
Please identify the problem

Comment: There is a very useful MSDN article about migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0, and although it's from 2.2 not 2.1 I still think it could be very helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Have tried the things but didn't work. then reverted my setting back. I copied my whole class here so that anybody who have follow following path might help.

Comment: trying again with more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes eventually work for 2.1 to 3.0 path.
One manual change i am doing is updating newtonsoft to new builtin json type in all places where it doesn't break
(e.g for one case i have to still use newtonsoft where i am serializing Formcollection and QueryCollection of the request)

```
namespace MyApp.Interfaces
{
    public class StartupShutdownHandler
    {

        public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).
            ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>{}).UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<StartupShutdownHandler>();

        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private const string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";


        public StartupShutdownHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddControllers(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(); //updated            
            CorsRelatedPolicyAddition(services);
        }

        private void CorsRelatedPolicyAddition(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var lstofCors = ConfigurationHandler.GetSection<List<string>>(StringConstants.AppSettingsKeys.CorsWhitelistedUrl);
            if (lstofCors != null && lstofCors.Count > 0 && lstofCors.Any(h => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(h)))
            {
                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => { builder.WithOrigins(lstofCors.ToArray()).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
                });

            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {                
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });            
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(StartedApplication);
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
        }


        private void OnShutdown()
        {
             Logger.Debug("Application Ended");
        }

        private void StartedApplication()
        {
            Logger.Debug("Application Started");
        }
    }
}
```